# Selenium not loading javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

The data that I wanted to extract is loaded through google tag manager. I tried with chrome and firefox and every time the li elements that I needed in the body come up empty, regardless of timing.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

opt = uc.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
opt.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

URL = 'https://cannotsharetheurl'

browser.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I found is that the headless option causes the website to disable the scripts.
The work around was to change the user agent to avoid getting caught.

To check the user agent:

```
print(browser.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent'))
```

This was returning

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) HeadlessChrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Overriding the user agent:

```
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})
```

Once the headless user agent is hidden the page started to load normally